# Passing Url In Variable That Contains Values With '&' sign

Tags: php

I Want to pass Url inside one variable, this variable contains url with values.
for example:

```
$addr = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
echo $addr;
```

this step will give me `http://localhost/index.php?page=3&var1=A&var2=B`

When i passing this $addr var to another page, and echo it, i get only `` `http://localhost/index.php?page=3 ``

 its look like when there is & sign its gone.
what should i do? there is way to pass this variable and echo the whole var?
thanks.

Comment: How do you pass `$addr` to another page? Aren't you redirecting to it?

Comment: no, i`m redirecting with another variables, but i want to know what the page i came from with all of his parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) them. A quick Google search shows me that simply replacing `&` with `%26` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get at least all the values after question mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (but be careful as it's not 100% reliable).

Another option would be to add it to the URL.

```
$addr = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
$addr = urlencode($addr);
$yourUrl = 'http://wwww.google.com?var1=4'; // some url
header("Location:{$yourUrl}&from={$addr}");
```

That's about it.